# R programming: Assign a columns but only with specific values in another column

Tags: r, variables, assign

From my dataset 'DataHP2' I assigned columns 8,9,10,14,15,16,18,19 and 20 to variable 'd'
So far soo good!

```
d <- DataHP2[c(8:10,14:16,18:20)]
```

Now I want to create another variable 'dl' that assigns the same columns BUT only for those values of these columns that ALSO have a valye of '1' in column 12.
How am I going to code this?

Comment: Try `d1 <- d[d[[12]]==1,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do it with which() function

dl <- DataHP2[which(DataHP2[12] == 1),c(8:10,14:16,18:20)]